# SQL - Invalid column name that was just declared

Tags: sql-server

I have some code like this that keeps throwing an "invalid column name" error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SampleProcedure
    CREATE TABLE #WorkTable(
        ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        ForeignKeyID INT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO #WorkTable(ID, ForeignKeyID)
    SELECT 1, 1
```

And I keep getting this error from the procedure when it is invoked:

> Invalid column name 'ForeignKeyID'. Line 6 in SampleProcedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a parent procedure already defined a temp table by the same name without the column [ForeignKeyID], so the child procedure that defined the temp table was being improperly parsed by SQL.

The true error *should be*

> There is already an object named '#TempTable' in the database.

My fix was to change the child procedure's temp table to be a table variable instead.

P.S. I'm putting this question/answer here for other people scratching their head at the crummy error messages in SQL Server.

Comment: Good place to use `if object_id('tempdb..#WorkTable') is not null drop table #WorkTable` or in your case, since the parent proc needs it, replace drop table with `RAISEERROR()` preferably in a `TRY / CATCH`

Comment: why not use table variable?

Comment: I switched the child procedure to use a table variable and that fixed it. It had no reasonable expectation that any parent caller would have already declared temp tables with the same name, so it was just by chance it happened now.